# Дата из c# в Angular

Tags: c#, json, angular2, typescript, asp.net-web-api

Получаю данные из `Web API` в формате `json`. Даты имеют такой вид:

```
2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z
```

Пытаюсь передать дату в `input type=“date”`

```
<input type=“date” [(ngModel)]=“item.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'" />
```

Но `input` остаётся пустой. Как правильно занести дату в `input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто. Формат у `input type="date"`: **`yyyy-MM-dd`**.

```
<input [ngModel]="event.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="event.date = $event"  class="form-control" type="date" />
```

Теперь дата корректно выводится в `input`.